# discord.py bot doesn't work without 'Administrator' permissions

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I made a Discord bot using discord.py, but my bot doesn't work at all without the 'Administrator' permission, and I get this error: `Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions`.

I even tried to give the bot every permission except 'Administrator', but it still didn't work.
My bot sends messages, deletes users' messages if needed and finds the first text channel in the server, so I tried giving it only "send messages", "manage messages", and "manage channels", but nothing.

I need to avoid giving the bot Administrator permissions.
I tried this very basic code:

```py
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
   print("test")
```

But it didn't work as well; I gave the bot the following permissions: 'send messages', 'manage messages', 'embed links', 'read message history', 'manage channels' and 'read messages'/'view channels'.
This is what I import:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import asyncio
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
```

Comment: Do you want to avoid making the 'administrator' permission mandatory? When do you get the `Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions` error? Please [edit] your question to include the full traceback and relevant code.

Comment: Try using `intents = discord.Intents.all()` instead of `intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True`. Also, do you have [the necessary intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html) enabled on [your Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)?